# Markdown Editing Helper in Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

Stack Overflow has a very useful Markdown editing helper, especially for someone who doesn't have a strong HTML background:

[image]

I think it would be good if this toolbar and inline help was also added in the Developer Story section.

For example, in  **Position → Responsibilities** , we usually use a bulleted list to list our job descriptions. Instead of typing multiple `<li>` like `<ul> <li>...</li> <li>...</li> </ul>`, isn't it better if we can simply use `Bulleted List` option from the Markdown editing helper?

Comment: Simply type `*` or `-` for bullet list items.

Comment: @Xufox doesn't work. It will only print `- some text` without proper format (indent, newline, etc)

Comment: @gameon67 It does that when you don't add an empty line before it, similar to how it works in posts.

Comment: @Dukeling I see, that's why I'm asking this feature should be provided at other sections as well to provide guidance for "common" people who's not familiar with markup language